# Как игнорировать (не выполнять) условие @before (junit, selenium, java)

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

Привет !

Пишу тест связка java+maven+selenium+junit , структура такая @before @Test @Test @Test .... @after  - вот в тесте , который в середине мне не надо выполнять предусловие @before, там надо открыть другой ресурс и в нем внести корректировки , а дальше все остальные тесты уже вместе с @before . Подскажите пожалуйста , как проигнорировать выполнение предусловия @before ?

Comment: можно вынести тест в отдельный класс (если ничто другое не мешает это сделать, конечно)

Comment: Мне важно , соблюдение очередности выполнения

Comment: тогда можно убрать аннотацию `@Before`, а вместо этого вызывать метод явно в тех тестах, где нужно

Comment: Я не понимаю немного , у меня есть анотация ```@Test``` - в ней я пишу метод и описываю действия , Как мне в этом случае вызвать метод из анотации ```@before``` , в случае если я уберу её ?

Comment: Я имею в виду сделать метод, на котором сейчас стоит аннотация `@before`, приватным и убрать аннотацию. первым шагом в тестах (где нужно) вызывать этот приватный метод `myBeforeMethod()`